# pulse width modulation

Tags: pwm, verilog, xilinx, counter, delay

I need help on number one of this practice assignment. I barely learned about this so it is kind of hard me to understand it right now. So any advice or help is appreciated.

I want to determine the amount of delay in clk cycles needed to generate a PWM with a period of 0.05 ms.

What i did to determine the amount of delay was to divide 0.05 ms over the clk freq. which is 0.05ms/10^-8. The answer I get is 5000. Is this correct?

Comment: <strike>The most basic of maths. You know how long one clock period is (\$T=1/f\$). You know how long one PWM period is. So you divided one by the other and got an answer. Why do you think it is wrong?</strike>. Just realised the question is slightly different from my initial though.

Comment: I barely learned about this. I am mostly confused with trying to understand the math and the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the question before I commented, so will post some hints for you. I'm not going to give you an answer as it's your assignment to do.

One period of your counter needs to be \$0.05\mathrm{ms}\$. So that means it needs to count from 0 to its maximum value in that time. So from that you can work out at what frequency the counter needs to count at (hint: it is an 8bit counter, so what's the maximum value?). This gives you your required \$f_{enable}\$.

However, you don't have a clock of that frequency, instead you have one of \$100\mathrm{MHz}\$. The questions use of the word "Delay" is quite misleading and not a very good description. In fact the "Delay Counter" is a clock divider - it generates a clock enable signal which allows something to count at a lower frequency.

Look at the diagram, notice how the "Delay" is connected to an "Enable" pin. You can infer from this that the counter must be enabled for one \$100\mathrm{MHz}\$ clock cycle in every \$n\$ cycles. By doing this the counter will count at a frequency of \$f_{enable}=\frac{100\mathrm{MHz}}{n}\mathrm{Hz}\$.

What value of \$n\$ must be used to make the required period counter frequency?

Comment: To find n I use n = log base 2 of (2500 + 1). is what I am doing correct?

Comment: @cmelo Erm, no. Have you worked out the frequency of the period counter yet? (second paragraph of my answer).

Comment: If freq is f = 1/t i get f = 1/(0.05x10^(-3)) = 20000

Comment: @cmelo that's the frequency of the PWM period, but not how fast the perfod counter needs to count - it needs to count from 0 to it's maximum value in that time, so what is the frequency of the clock required to drive the period counter.

Comment: the max value is 8. So i would multiply the freq. by 8, which give 160000

Comment: @cmelo 8 is the number of bits. What is the maximum value of a 8 bit counter.

Comment: 2^8 which is 256

Comment: @cmelo correct. So what frequency must the period counter run at.

Comment: (freq.)(max value of counter) = (20000)(256) = 5120000 Hz

Comment: @cmelo So what's the value of n required to make that frequency and you have your answer.

Comment: n = (100MHz)/(fEnable) = (10^8)/(5120000) = 19.53

Comment: Would 19.53 be the amount of "delay"? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: @cmelo as I say, the term "delay" is a bad description. But essentially yes, every 19.53 clock cycles at 100MHz the period counter needs to tick. Either call it 20 (period would be 1.2us too long) or call it 19 (period would be about 1.3us too short).

Comment: alright. Thank you for your help and patience. I will continue the assignment and as well to study some notes I have. If i have some questions I will ask. Thank you once again.